# Can anyone explain the following PHP Code?

Tags: php

Can anyone explain the following PHP Code ?

```
function get_param($param_name, $param_type = 0)
    {
      global $HTTP_POST_VARS, $HTTP_GET_VARS;

      $param_value = "";
        if (isset($_POST)) {
          if (isset($_POST[$param_name]) && $param_type != GET)
          $param_value = $_POST[$param_name];
          elseif (isset($_GET[$param_name]) && $param_type != POST)
          $param_value = $_GET[$param_name];
        } else {
          if (isset($HTTP_POST_VARS[$param_name]) && $param_type != GET)
          $param_value = $HTTP_POST_VARS[$param_name];
          elseif (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS[$param_name]) && $param_type != POST)
          $param_value = $HTTP_GET_VARS[$param_name];
        }

        return strip($param_value);
    }

function strip($value)
    {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 0) {
            return $value;
        } else {
            return stripslashes($value);
        }
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

It is used like this:

```
$xml = get_param('xml');
```

Comment: What specifically do you have a problem with?

Comment: I want to know what the above function does ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code gets the value from the get and post data arrays. It also strips slashes on php installations that have magic quotes enabled. It looks like the function is made for backwards compatibility with older version of PHP. I wouldn't use this unless you are required to support older versions of PHP.

You don't need to make any changes for this to work in PHP 5, however I would just do the following:
For Get data:

```
if(isset($_GET['param_name'])){
    // What ever you want to do with the value
}
```

For Post data:

```
if(isset($_POST['param_name'])){
    // What ever you want to do with the value
}
```

You should also read up on [Magic Quotes](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) since it was not deprecated till PHP 5.3.0 and you may need to be concerned about it.

The updated function could also be written as:

```
function get_param($param_name, $param_type = 0)
{

  $param_value = "";
  if (isset($_POST[$param_name]) && $param_type != GET){
      $param_value = $_POST[$param_name];
  }
  elseif (isset($_GET[$param_name]) && $param_type != POST){
      $param_value = $_GET[$param_name];
  }
  return strip($param_value);
}
```

Strip can be left alone.

Comment: If I want change it for PHP 5.1+ , what changes do I have to make ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything for PHP 5.1+.

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to know how to remove the backwards compatibility from 5.1 and below

Comment: Added an updated function, the references to $HTTP_*_VARS were removed.

Comment: Could the above code be changed to use $_REQUEST, instead of using both $_POST and $_GET since $_REQUEST collects data sent from both $_GET and $_POST ?

Comment: You could, `$_REQUEST` also holds cookie information as well. Just note that some of the GET values could be over ridden by the POST one (or vice versa) depending on your configuration. Take a look at the PHP manual.

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_param($param_name, $param_type = 0)
```

This returns a parameter value, with a given type, POST, or GET, *which is optional*. The value is stripped of slashes.

```
function strip($value)
```

This returns the parameter without slashes.

I agree with the other comments that this code was written prior to 2003, and should not be used, unless for supporting old code.

Comment: You might want to add that the given type is optional.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some insane way of making sure you're getting the correct GET/POST vars.
Most of the code from get_param() seems to be a way to make the code work on almost any php version, since it's using the legacy methods, you should have a look at the [PHP Manual about _GET](http://es.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)/_POST

Answer (score 1):

The code is a function that takes a parameter's name (`$param_name`) and the HTTP request type it's expected to be found in (GET or POST), then looks through the current (`$_GET` and `$_POST`) and deprecated (`$HTTP_GET_VARS` and `$HTTP_POST_VARS`) request variable arrays for a value matching that name. Before it returns, it tries to strip extra slashes out of the value it found.

So for example, if I passed this HTTP request:

```
http://www.example.com/explain_function.php?key=value
```

then ran the function

```
get_param("key", "GET");
```

It would return "value".

Answer (score 0):

It appears that is is trying to extract a value from the query string based on the name of the parameter.  It is first checking to see if the $_POST variable is valid, and if not, check the $HTTP_POST_VARS.  If either one of them are valid, it will return the value with the name of $param_name.  For instance, if $param_name = "foo", it will check $_POST["foo"].